# What happens to offset commit when the record processing took more than 'max.poll.interval.ms'?

Tags: apache-kafka

I've below consumer settings.

```
auto.offset.reset=earliest
enable.auto.commit=true (default value)
session.timeout.ms=10000 (default value)
max.poll.interval.ms= 300000 (default value)
```

With the above configuration, let's say i got a message and because of some network latency at the DB call, it's processing took 300100 ms. Now I've two questions

1. Would the consumer be able to commit the offset properly or would it be considered as dead & removed from the group because it's not able to process the record within 'max.poll.interval.ms'?
2. If the consumer is considered as dead and offset was committed, would the next poll pick this offset again for processing?

Comment: yes, it answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Consumers never move ahead in offsets without committing previous

If your code takes longer, then there will be a log message indicating as such and the consumer group will rebalance

FWIW, if you're doing database lookups, the idea is that you pull your database events into a topic/KTable, then join against that data

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just mentioned database lookup as an example but my concern is, because of any kind of reason, if the processing gets delayed, then what happens to that record/message. Since the offset is not committed, would it be available for next poll?

Comment: If you're polling the oldest message, there's always the possibility that it will become unavailable in the next poll

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Have you tried reading Kafka Definitive Guide book?

Comment: I've started reading that book